# setTimeout inside for loop doesn't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am creating a function that when you press a button it pops up a random symbol one at a time with a delay inbetween and then changes to a readable word once all symbols load up. I can't get the delay to work. I havent added the part that will turn the symbols into a readable word yet because I cant finish this.

```
//Brute Force
function work() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        $('#txtBrute').append($sym[$rand]);
    },1000);
};
var i = 1;
var $sym = [1,9,"%","$",")",">","@","?","-","|",7];
$('#btnBrute').click(function() {
    var $pass = "password123";
    $('#txtBrute').html("");
    for(i = 1; i <= $pass.length; i++) {
        work();
    };
});
```

Comment: Pass `i` to `work` and multiply the delay by `i`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're calling `work()` in a loop, so all the timers execute immediately.

Instead of this you could make `work()` recursive. You can use the length of the password as a decremental value over each recursion. Try this:

```js
var timeout;
var $sym = [1, 9, "%", "$", ")", ">", "@", "?", "-", "|", 7];

function work(length) {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var $rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    $('#txtBrute').append($sym[$rand]);
    --length != 0 && work(length);
  }, 1000);
};

$('#btnBrute').click(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  var pass = "password123";
  $('#txtBrute').html("");
  work(pass.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnBrute">Go</button>
<div id="txtBrute"></div>
```

Also note that I added a `clearTimeout()` call, should someone decide to keep pressing the button while the recursive loop is still running.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout()` doesn't affect when the rest of the code is run, so the loop launches all timeouts at once. As a result, they are all called at once, after 1000 milliseconds. Rory's answer suggests making `work()` recursive; another way to solve this, perhaps easier to implement but not as usable, would to pass a delay amount into `work()`:

```js
function work(delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        $('#txtBrute').append($sym[$rand]);
    }, delay);
};

var i = 1;
var $sym = [1,9,"%","$",")",">","@","?","-","|",7];

$('#btnBrute').click(function() {
    var $pass = "password123";
    $('#txtBrute').html("");
    for(i = 1; i <= $pass.length; i++) {
        work(i * 1000);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnBrute">Go</button>
<pre id="txtBrute"></pre>
```

Comment: While this works, the disadvantage is that you cannot control all the queued timers if the button is clicked multiple times. You would need to store them in an array when created then clear them individually

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I hadn't thought about that. Perhaps it would be easier to just use `setInterval` instead; what advantages/disadvantages does that have over recursively using `setTimeout`?

Comment: Interval would solve the issue of multiple button presses, you'd just need to keep track of how many times the timer has executed and stop it when needed.